# SharePoint 2010 Changing URL's in Master Pages on its own

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Wondering if others have seen this.

We know after doing a major catch-up patching of our sharepoint servers in January, that the system changed a bunch of urls in master pages and some other files.  generally cutting up existing absolute url's or //-type urls.  Normally cutting off an external server.domain.name from the url...implying it thought this stuff was on our web app.

Well we finally figured out that the system had altered the files and we put it down to something involved with all the patching.

On 4/20, we found one file that the system appeared to touch on its own again.  We know how this file used to look and that what was changed existed correctly prior to that date.   Also the version history says no one has touched the file since March.

So...now we're wondering how to tell when SharePoint is touching files on its own since apparently the changes don't get tagged in version history.
Also, does anyone know if there's an identifiable service that does this so that we can monitor and estimate if or when it might happen again?

Comment: We have a public-facing SharePoint 2010 publishing site. The master has been customized (via SharePoint Designer) and contains links to outside resources like code libraries, analytics tracking, and Facebook widgets.  In January we applied a large number of patches, we were a year and a half behind on patching. After applying the patches we found that the external resource links in the master had their domain names chopped off, so "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js" became "/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js".

Comment: This broke a lot of stuff because the page was now looking for these resources in the wrong spot, on our server instead of where they actually were. We couldn't find a reason for this so we fixed the URLs and attributed it to patching weirdness.

Comment: However, it has happened again.  This time only 2 urls in the master were affected, instead of all of them, but it was the same thing. The domain name was chopped off turning it into a local absolute link. The version history for the master doesn't show anyone having edited it at the time the problem started, SharePoint seems to have made this change itself.

Comment: Has anyone run into any issues like this?  Any guesses about what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "touch files"? Any file residing in the 14 / 15 "Hive" under Program Files\Common etc are part of the system and should never be changed manually. 
Any changes to files like PageLayouts and Master Pages you should do either in Visual Studio (VS) (and deploy with a solution / app) or through SharePoint Designer SPD).

Any changes made on the actual file system can (and WILL) be overwritten.
Any changes you make to the files in the regular way (i.e. VS or SPD) will never be changed by SharePoint itself. Changes made using SPD will "ghost" a file, i.e. store a custom version in the content database, files deployed using Visual Studio will be stored on the file system (and are also "ghostable" after being made available in a site through a feature activation or app).

Comment: the files changed don't exist in the file system.